# How to force the checkout of the latest revision from a remote server?

Tags: git

I have repository on GitHub to which I commit regularly from my local computer. On the other side I have server pulling from the repository. The web server just executes a `git pull` in order to get the latest changes from the GitHub repository. This is completely automated and should stay that way (solutions like the Ruby Tool Capistrano are out).

A simple `git pull` usually works just fine. However, sometimes I change the last commit (`git commit --amend`) and `git push` the changes twice to GitHub. If the server auto-updated it's code between the two pushes to GitHub, the next server side `git pull` fails because there is merge conflict.

To solve this problem I need the following behavior: The server should continue to `git pull` (or something equivalent) the GitHub repository but in case of a merge conflict, the GitHub repository should just take precedence over the local repository on the server. So, I want a git command that behaves like `git clone`, but doesn't copy the whole repository every single time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JB's right, but I'm going to expand a bit on his answer.

Instead of having the server automatically run `git pull`, you should have it run `git fetch origin; git checkout origin/master`. Of course, this assumes that you've got the "origin" remote set up to refer to your local computer's repo.

If you ever need to modify the server sources directly (for a quick fix, or whatever) and want to commit those changes, you can `git branch -f master origin/master` before you do the commit to get the server's master branch set to the same commit as the local computer's branch.

Answer (score 7):

You can of course do the forced git checkout if you don't do any local modifications there, but the right answer would be to *never ever amend commits that have left your local repository*.

Comment: I know, but I guess it doesn't matter since I'm currently the only user of that remote repository.

Comment: But now you see it does matter. Because the other computer is also a user. But now that you put the question this way — does it mean that you're asking how to resync it once?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with amending commits if only one *person* is working with the repositories (no matter how many repos there are). Unless that person is concerned about confusing him/herself, they can always do checkouts, resets, or forced updates to get multiple repos back in sync.

Comment: Dan, this question exactly demonstrates what's wrong with amending commits in one-man-repo. Exactly confusing the hell out of himself and his computers ;-). I'd say *there's nothing wrong with amending commits as long as you are aware of implications and are ready to deal with them*.

Comment: Give a man a fish, or teach him to fish? Telling him not to amend his commits is like giving him the fish... I'd rather he learn :)

Comment: @hacker: The real danger I see with amending commits is with amending a commit that someone else has begun using as a base upon which to do their own work. That will certainly lead to a confusing situation that will require careful attention and merging. But if you're working alone, this usually won't be a problem.

Comment: I think it's cleaner to use amend sometimes, and when you are working alone there is no problem. I understand that it could be problem if are working with a team or in an Open Source environment, but that's not the case here. A clean history is worth something too, right? The reason I use amend is that I don't want to have extra commits just to fix a misspelled comment in the source code.

Comment: Dan, it takes time to learn to fish and it hard to go this route hungry ;-)
Christoph, it is cleaner to use amend, but you should normally have enough time for amendments before the code leaves your repository.
But then again — as long as you know how to deal with it, it's just fine and you're the one to decide whether you do or don't want to amend.

Answer (score 4):

I you never modify the sources you `pull`, what you probably want to do is just `fetch` then `checkout`.